# Adding SKPhysicsBody causes the SKSpriteNode to shake

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have two `SkSpriteNodes` called `left-ball` and `right-ball`.THey flow from sides of the screen.

I implemented the `collision detection` for these two balls. However I noticed that before I add collision detection, the balls were moving smoothly without any shaking effect, but after I add the collision detection, the balls were shaking and moving in their path.

I am using the same bit category for both of these balls:

```
   static const int ballHitCategory = 1;
```

**without shaking:**

[image]

**with shaking:**

[image]

Here is what I tried in code:

```
_leftBall.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_leftBall.frame.size];
_leftBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=ballHitCategory;
_leftBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=ballHitCategory;
_leftBall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=ballHitCategory;
_leftBall.physicsBody.dynamic=YES;
_leftBall.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection=YES;

 _rightBall.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_rightBall.frame.size];
_rightBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=ballHitCategory;
_rightBall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask=ballHitCategory;
_rightBall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask=ballHitCategory;
_rightBall.physicsBody.dynamic=YES;
_rightBall.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection=YES;




-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

    _leftBall = (SKSpriteNode*)contact.bodyA.node;
    _rightBall = (SKSpriteNode *)contact.bodyB.node;

    if(_leftBall.physicsBody .categoryBitMask == ballHitCategory ||  _rightBall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask == ballHitCategory)
    {

        NSLog(@" hit the ");
        //setup your methods and other things here
        [_leftBall removeFromParent];
        [_rightBall removeFromParent];


    }
}
```

Please note that shake happens only after I add the collision detection, If I remove the above code, everything is fine.

What is the proper way to add collision detection without effecting the skspritenode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so youre moving the sprites using non physics code.. but theyre still part of the physics simulation.  I'm guessing theyre fighting against the force of gravity.

either set `affectedByGravity` on each sprite to false

or you can turn off gravity in your game completely

```
[self.physicsWorld setGravity:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
```

Comment: so when do we need the gravity ?

Comment: lets say when the two balls hit each other, i want them to fall down, do I need gravity in that case ? @hamobi

Comment: you can just manually set their velocity to go down.. or if you want it to look more natural you could use gravity.  

maybe allow your physics world to have gravity.  make the balls not affected by gravity until they hit eachother

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the Gravity. You should set your spritenode:

```
_leftBall.physicsBody.dynamic=YES;
_leftBall.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=NO;
```

Same on _rightBall